# I want to categorize cities and counties in UK based on the region they belong to using JSON

Tags: python, json, geopandas

So I have two UK datasets, one has housing prices by cities and counties (housing_df), another has unemployment rates by region (unemp_p_df). I want to merge the two but the issue that I am facing is that none of the datasets have postcode or coordinates data in them. I tried using a GeoJSON file to put the cities in their respective regions.

I downloaded UK's [(Counties and Unitary Authorities (May 2021) UK BFC)](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/34cae3dd946847f78b6dfc6bd5add3c7_0/explore) GeoJSON file from https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/
and have turned it into a dataframe with geopandas.
[picture of the resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tvO9.png)

How can I use this to categorize cities in one of my datasets into regions so that I can merge both of the datasets together?

Comment: If you download the CSV dataset, that includes longitude and latitude values. There's a free API at https://findthatpostcode.uk that will facilitate mapping lon/lat to a postcode

Comment: The data that I downloaded only had area-codes for some reason, no postcodes.

Comment: Right - That's what I'm telling you. If you download the CSV you'll get lon/lat values for the Unitary Authorities and Counties. You can then lookup postcodes using the API that I mentioned. Having said that, I'm not sure how useful that would be. For example, if the UA is Buckinghamshire, the the lon/lat and consequent postcode is just somewhere in the middle of the county